# Requesting Bansuri/Venu tag

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I humbly request Bansuri/Venu tag. Bansuri is Hindustani Classical flute, while Venu is Carnatic Classic flute (from melodious South India).

**Update: Bansuri tag created March 13th 2019 by Community**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems perfectly reasonable to add `bansuri` and `venu` tags to questions specific to those instruments. Once you have 300 reputation you'll be able to create these yourself - if you still feel they're necessary.  See https://music.stackexchange.com/help/privileges.

Answer (score 6):

The general consensus seems to be that tags should not be created to proactively make space for questions, but only after a significant number of questions have appeared that would benefit from them.

Currently, [I only see one question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/65001/difference-between-6-holed-and-7-holed-indian-bamboo-flute?r=SearchResults&s=1|47.1036) about Bansuri or Venu. One question does not seem to justify a new tag, and that question is tagged [flute](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flute) and [indian-classical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-classical), which would seem to be sufficient in the absence of a more compelling need.

Looking again, I had searched for questions containing both Bansuri *and* Venu and came up with only one, but it appears that there are currently two questions about Venu and nine about Bansuri. By the numbers, I think that this might be enough to justify a new tag. However, I am still uncertain that one is needed. It seems that [flute](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flute) and [indian-classical](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indian-classical) together should be fine, and I don't see what would be gained.

Comment: I'd add that tags are really just to help search engines and sorting. They already look in the body and title so if those words are in the question, search engines will still find the post.

Comment: @DoktorMayhem As you've explained, tags don't really help search engines. Their 
main use is to let people subscribe to topics they're interested in and ignore topics they're not interested in.

Comment: I've posted 4 or 5 questions regarding Bansuri. Totally understand there must be lots and lots of questions

Comment: @DavidBowling Well, indian classical music encompasses not only bansuri/venu, but countless other such as sitar (think Anoushka Shankar), tabla, etc, etc. And the saptak, which is equivalent to `do re me fo so la ti do`

Comment: oh, i see ... @DavidBowling ...